# Writing entitiy names in intent [IBM Watson]

Tags: chatbot, ibm-watson

I have a question about IBM Watson Chatbot and intents.
For Example i have 2 Entitys and one Intent.
Entity @Cybercrime:{
Phising,
Malware,
DDoS,
Botnet
}
Entity @DDoS_types:{
Ping_Flooding,
Mail Bombing,
Syn Flooding
}
must i have to write a "@" in in the intents?
For example
What is @Cybercrime @DDoS:types
or is it enough if i write only "What is"?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how you are planning to use the intent. You need to put enough variations to remove doubt and allow for variations so the service can obtain high certainty for the intent that you intended.

If you only train it with "what is", then the question "what is Phising?" could get confused with questions like "what is a good strategy against Phising?"